# What is the resource definition address of XRD in resim

Tags: smartcontracts, scrypto

I want to transfer XRD to another account in the simulator but I don't know its resource definition address.

What is it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The address of the resource definition of the Radix token in the `resim` simulator, as of v0.5 is `resource_sim1qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqzqu57yag`

For example, if you want to send 3000 XRD to another account you created with `resim new-account`, you would write:

```
resim transfer 3000 resource_sim1qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqzqu57yag [account2_address]
```